# Mongo Ruby :connecttimeoutms disappeared?

Tags: ruby, mongodb

I've been using the connection option `:connecttimeoutms` when setting up MongoDB connections using the mongodb ruby gem. Like so:

```
connection = Connection.from_uri(uri, :connecttimeoutms => connect_timeout)
```

Now getting warnings that

```
connecttimeoutms is not a valid option for Mongo::Connection
```

since a recent `bundle update`.

Has this disappeared? Does anyone know what I should replace it with?

Comment: the better answer is to read the sources and find out valid options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@sumskyi is absolutely right of course

After such investigation it seems it is now `:connect_timeout` and is measured in seconds

Thanks